# Not getting stable output out of ADC

Tags: adc, atmega

I have written a short program to measure the room temperature using a temp sensor, LM335. The power supply is fixed pretty constant at 5.04V. The following code is supposed to print out the second digit of the temperature and show it on a seven segment output. I followed the same procedure to get the first digit and it worked. However, this particular one doesn't seem to work..

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

uint16_t readADC(uint8_t channel) {
    ADMUX = (0xf0 & ADMUX) | channel;
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);

    while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);
    return(ADC);
}

int main(void) {

uint16_t sensorValue;
double voltage,tempC,c;
int tempInt;

// Common Anode Configuration

int lookup[10] = {
    0x3f, 0x6, 0x5b, 0x4f, 0x66,
    0x6d, 0x7d, 0x7, 0xff, 0x6f
};

DDRD=0xff;
PORTD=0b00000000;

//Set up ADC
ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);

while (1) {
    sensorValue = readADC(0);
    _delay_ms(1000);
    voltage= 5.04/1023.0*sensorValue;

    tempC=(voltage*100-273.15);
    tempInt=(int)tempC;

    c=(tempC-tempInt)*10; 
    onesPart=(int)c;
    PORTD=lookup[onesPart];

    } 
    return (0);
}
```

The temperature here is about 31 C right now. The second digit is 1 but the readings are quite misleading. Sometimes it shows 2, 3, and even 7 or 8! I don't know what's the problem with the code.

I use Atmega8a's built-in ADC. It has 10 bit resolution so it does have enough precision. The analog input to ADC0 was 3.04V, resulting in a temperature of 304-273=31 C. The second digit is expected to be 1 not something else. Since it's the first time I've used ADC I might have got something wrong. Any thought is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your schematic. It could be analog noise due to lack of decoupling.

Comment: Put your finger on the sensor. Does the code spread change?

Comment: Take the top 6 or 8 bits of ADC data (top 1 or 2 bits may never change, so ignore them if never change) and wire those bits to 10Kohm, 20KOhm, 39Kohm 82Kohm, 160Khm, 330Kohm, 680Kohm, 1.2MegOhm. You have a 8-bit DAC. Tie those 8 resistors together, into a 1Kohm Summer. Put scope on the 1Kohm Vout.

Comment: I would first check the MCU's power supply with an oscilloscope. Is it really so stable as you say? Your problem may come from there. 
But then I don't understand what you are trying to do! You want to print the "1" from the "31" reading and it is printed wrong? As far as I understand it, when you do the substraction of tempInt from tempC, you get the decimal part of tempC.